# How to get value from json in ios application

Tags: ios, json

i am getting response from the server in below method:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data{
    NSString * result;
   NSMutableData * _responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [_responseData appendData:data];

    NSDictionary *dataAsString=(NSDictionary*)[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"data in register reponse : %@",dataAsString);
```

I get this json value on logs:

```
dataAsString : {"status":"error","message":"MySQL Error: 1062 : Duplicate entry 'raushan@gmail.com' for key 'loginEmail'"}
```

Now I want to get a particular value from the string ,e.g. for key "status": 
like the method below:

```
 Nsstring * result=[dataAsString objectForKey:@"status"];
 NSLog(@"result : %@",result);
```

but I dodn't get the result and my application crashes. I don't know what is wrong with that. I had tried a lots of way but not succeeded.

Please help me out. How can I retrieve value from `dataAsString`.
Thank you for your precious time.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSJSONSerialization *json;
NSDictionary *dataJson;
NSError *error;

json=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_responseData
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                          error:&error];

dataJson=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
dataJson=(NSDictionary *)json;
NSString * result=[dataJson valueForKey:@"status"];
```

if you are having more trouble, refer this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/) and [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: you don't need to alloc init a separate NSDictionary, just cast json and you'll be fine.

Comment: sir, please tell me what is this responsData,when i used responsData in place of dataAsString my application crashes.please specify how to use json serialization. thank you

Comment: i  am getting this error:    -[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa6ef9d0
2014-07-11 14:24:56.481 PicBackMefhbgerhb[2408:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa6ef9d0'

Comment: Since it's just pair of strings, you have to use valueForKey

Comment: if it works for you, you have to accept the answer, then only others having the same problem , will be able find it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *parsedObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receiveddata options:0 error:&localError];
NSDictionary *result = [dataAsString objectForKey:@"result"];
NSString *statusString = [result objectForKey:@"status"];
```